Docker Container Running a NextJS app in host networking mode won't start due to address not available
I've got a nextjs container that runs fine until I try to run it in host networking mode. Here's the command I run:
docker run --net=host --name myapp_ui myimage_ui
This is the I get when it tries to run:
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available fdc4:f303:9324::7:3000
I've checked repeatedly and nothing is running on port 3000. I'm not sure why it won't run. Is there something I'm missing that needs to be in the dockerfile for host networking, or is there something else I need to consider? Additionally I'm not sure why the container is being assigned an ipv6 address.

Do you have the same problem running the application without Docker?  You should rarely if ever need host networking, especially for a Web application front-end; does docker run -p 3000:3000 with a more normal networking setup work?

@DavidMaze, no I don't have a problem running it without docker. Admittedly I'm fairly new to docker, but, as I understand it, host networking is a necessity for my app. The app needs to reach out to a graphql api for content that is on another network. I thought host network was the only way to do that. Is there another way?
Running it in a container with normal networking, my app is not able to reach out to the api. I get a connection refused error.

What URL are you trying to call?  Using a DNS FQDN or a manual IP address should work fine, even with the default ("bridge") networking mode.  If you're using a VM-based setup like Docker Desktop, it's a very recent change that host networking works at all.

I appreciate the comments @DavidMaze. I'm not sure what I did other than running it from CLI in default bridge mode instead of through docker desktop. Now the container is working and able to access outside resources. Weird. That said, i'm running into the same issue as before with the container running on Heroku. That's a question for a different place though I think.

Suggestion for troubleshoot:

Remove the --net=host to see if the container able to run
Check if any IPv4 address assigned to the docker server as you're using the host
Map to another port to see if the container able to run -p 3005:3000

